# Can't install SonataAdminBundle for Symfony 4

Tags: php, composer-php, sonata-admin, symfony4

Have installed via Composer clear Symfony 4.1

Then i try to install via Composer SonataAdmin but get error with message:

```
sonata-project/admin-bundle 3.38.3 requires symfony/class-loader ^2.8 || ^
3.2 -> satisfiable by symfony/class-loader[3.4.x-dev] but these conflict with yo
ur requirements or minimum-stability.
```

In symfony 4 documentation says, that symfony/class-loader component deleted in this version.

How can i install SonataAdmin for Symfony 4.1 using Composer?

Comment: Hi welcome to stack overflow! have you tried `composer why symfony/class-loader` or `composer why-not symfony/class-loader` ? Another lib in your vendor stuff obviously wants a different version. Try those to shine some light on it. Also, sometimes simply deleting your composer.lock file and trying again is enough to resolve this. Let me know how you get on and add any extra info to your question!

Comment: Composer why symfony/class-loader and composer why-not symfony/class-loader give the message: Could not find package "symfony/class-loader" in your project. Composer update did not solve the problem

Comment: ok rename composer.lock to composer.lock.backup and try the `composer require sonata-project/admin-bundle` again

Answer (score 0):

Solve this by installing symfony/class-loader:dev-master first, then install SonataAdmin